# SSL timeout on some sites, across all browsers, on Mac OS X Snow Leopard

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, ssl

For the past several weeks, I've been receiving `"Error 7 (net::ERR_TIMED_OUT): The operation timed out"` when I attempt to connect to either Twitter or Paypal via SSL. I get this specific error in Google Chrome, but the same problem occurs in both Safari and Firefox. Other sites work fine, and other computers on my network can access these two sites. I have no firewall settings that would prevent me from accessing these sites over port 443.

I notice that both Twitter and Paypal both have "Verisign Class 3 Extended Validation SSL CA" certificates. It is unclear whether this is related to the problem. In an effort to troubleshoot, I attempted to open the test sites referenced on Verisign's [root certificate support page](http://www.verisign.com/support/roots.html), which worked fine. Just to be sure, I downloaded and installed the root package file and installed all included Verisign certificates. No joy.

I feel like I've hit a dead end. Any ideas?

**Update the first:** I also cannot connect to FedEx.com, who also has a Verisign Class 3 Extended Validation cert.

**Update the second:** Aaaaaaand it fixed itself. I did nothing. Or, I did something that worked, but in a delayed fashion. Frustrating, but a win is a win. I'll take it.

Comment: @danays Do other SSL things work, e.g. Your Account in the iTunes Store, or logging-in in the Twitter app, or wget a https page?

Comment: I use Twitteriffic, which works fine, and presumably connects via the same API as the web-based Twitter interface.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, Apple Mail doesn't work (port 993 ssl timeout on gmail and our own domain), Chrome & Safari are off totally, only Firefox works (but prints "(unknown)" as the cert owner).

Comment: btw there are possible duplicates http://superuser.com/questions/347316/lion-unable-to-load-ssl-sites http://superuser.com/questions/273641/cannot-use-ssl-tls-on-mac-os-x