# Cannot use SSL/TLS on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, ssl, tls

I'm using a Mac I don't have administration rights on, so I can't create new accounts or anything like that. However, in my account (there's a general account in which everything works fine) I can't use anything requiring TLS/ SSL connections.

It's browser independent. The error is there, whether I use Chrome, Firefox or Safari. In Chrome it says it's an SSL connection error 107. However all definitions seem to be alright. I checked that in Firefox, though new interface for Under The Hood options in Chrome still puzzles me. However it seems as the problem is in some definition of the user account, rather than in the browser. I'm not acquainted with Mac OS, does anyone know how to solve this?

P.S.: I just wanted to add that it's definitely not a browser problem, since I face similar problems with MacHG and Dropbox.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have "Parental Controls", or something like that, turned on. I forget the exact config dialog location (it changes by release, anyway), but find it and turn it off. This option turns on a system wide HTTP proxy. SSL/TLS do not work through proxies.