# Lion Unable to Load SSL Sites

Tags: macos, google-chrome, osx-lion, ssl

OS: Mac 10.7.2 (Lion)

I've been unable to load any SSL sites on any browser. Chrome gives error 7 (ERR_TIMED_OUT), but this occurs across all browsers. I've tried different DNS, flushing DNS, and other things. No luck. Any advice?

Comment: Update: It sometimes works in Firefox. Not for every SSL site though.

Comment: This problem was maddening. Thanks for posting.

Comment: More info: http://superuser.com/questions/349740/mac-os-x-lion-10-7-2-update-breaks-ssl

Comment: Plenty of suggestions to this issue are logged here:
http://superuser.com/questions/349740/mac-os-x-lion-10-7-2-update-breaks-ssl/

Answer (score 3):

I found that the culprit is a corrupt Keychain file, as OS X can't access the Keychain program it can't check the necessary certificates so the page never loads.

Try opening the Keychain program now (*Applications > Utilities > Keychain*) and it shouldn't open (if it does, maybe the problem you're having is different).

- *Finder > Go > Go To Folder > `/Users/ENTER YOU USERNAME HERE/Library`*
- Find the `keychains` folder and delete the `login.keychain` file.
- You must reboot now. This forces Keychain to rebuild the corrupt file.

You should now be able to access the Keychain program and more importantly, load HTTPS / SSL websites!

Comment: This solution only works temporarily. Every time I restart or hibernate my MacBook, I have to do this all over again.

Comment: If you are suffering from problems having to do with a corrupt keychain, before resorting to deleting the keychain you should probably try to use Keychain First Aid from the Keychain Access application. That way you won't lose any valuable data if it happens to be stored in the keychain in question.

Comment: After removing this file and rebooting, I can finally log into SU and upvote.

Comment: This works, but there are two things: 1. You lose your password when you do that :)
2. It is not a fix. It is more like a bandage. Would be nice if anyone know a good solution to run keychain repair from terminal.

Comment: WARNING! I thought I could restore login.keychain and metadata.keychain from time machine... and I did... but... nothing changed at all, so I rebooted and COULDN'T LOGIN TO MY ACCOUNT! At least I have enabled SSH on my mac, so I logged from my other computer and deleted those *.keychain files from there. 2 minutes ago. No problems for now and SSL is working.